# Type mismatch. Required Context: Found MyAdapter.ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-mvvm

I am working on a small notes app where I am offline saving data in `SQLite'.

I have a class `MyAdapter` that is used to fill data in `RecycleView`. I have another `DatabaseHandler` class that is used to create a SQLite database.

I am following `MVVM` architecture that's why I need separate classes. I am getting a Type mismatch error. Can anybody help me to solve it?

```
class MyAdapter(private val perdata: ArrayList<PersonData>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var dbHandler: DatabaseHandler? = null
    var context:Context? = null
    var pos: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.ViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.contact_ticket, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return perdata.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.bind(perdata[position])

    }
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {

        pos = position
        return super.getItemId(position)
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
       /*
       constructor():super(){ //Error Primary constructor call expected
        }
       */
        fun bind(data: PersonData){

            itemView.et_surname.setText(data.firstname)
            itemView.et_first_name.setText(data.surname)
            itemView.et_company_name.setText(data.company_name)
            itemView.et_des.setText(data.des)
            itemView.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

                dbHandler = DatabaseHandler(this) //Type mismatch error here on this

           })    
        }
    } 
}
```

DatabaseHandler class is declared like this.

```
class DatabaseHandler(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSIOM){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because passing `this` to `DatabaseHandler` refers here to `ViewHolder` class not the `context`. If you want the `context` you can get it from itemView like the following:

```kotlin
  itemView.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

                dbHandler = DatabaseHandler(itemView.context)

           })
```